# how to update config.exs data without exiting iex?

Tags: elixir

My code is as follows:

```
import Config

# config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $metadata$message\n",
#   metadata: [:module, :function, :my_id]
    
    
config Mechanics,
ptz_port: "tty.usbserial-1410", 
ptz_speed: 115200, 
ptz_check_interval: 5000
```

ptz_port has been changed from "tty.usbserial-1420" to ""tty.usbserial-1410"

```
iex(16)> Application.get_all_env(Mechanics)          
[
  ptz_check_interval: 5000,
  imu_speed: 115200,
  ptz_port: "tty.usbserial-1430",
  testkey1: "value1",
  imu_port: "tty.usbserial-1420",
  ptz_speed: 115200,
  imu_pose: "horizon",
  imu_check_interval: 5000,
  key2: "value2"
]
```

When I trying to update config by calling `Config.config_env()`, the error is as follows. Is it possible to update config by command in iex without exiting it?

```
iex(18)> Config.config_env()
** (RuntimeError) could not set configuration via Config. This usually means you are trying to execute a configuration file directly, instead of reading it with Config.Reader
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/config.ex:91: Config.raise_improper_use!/0
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/config.ex:190: Config.__env__!/0
```

Answer (score 1):

`config.exs` is read at compile time.  You can put values in `runtime.exs` if you want them to be read when the application is started.  With a few technical exceptions for things that must be configured at compile-time, the runtime values will override the compile-time values -- perhaps this is how your `ptz_port` value was overridden.

In either case, the values are read into the application's process dictionary, so they can be read and modified during runtime (e.g. when you're in an `iex` session).  For example, you can put values into the application's process dictionary with a statement like this:

```
Application.put_env(Mechanics, ptz_speed: 4567)
```

There is an `Application.put_all_env/2` function, but you may encounter difficulties trying to reuse existing configuration files for this purpose.